# Getting [INS-13001] error. Oracle Database is not supported on this operating system

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

I am trying to install Oracle 19c on windows 11 but getting the below error.

[INS-13001] Oracle Database is not supported on this operating system. Installer will not perform prerequisite checks on the system.

I have performed the below task to resolve the issue but couldn't get through.

1.I extracted the installation folder to a different location and tried installation.

2.I tried to run the setup.exe file and setup application as administrator.

3.If I am skipping this error message(1_err.png), I am getting another error(2_err.png).

4.Stopping the OracleRemExecServiceV2 service and again tried installing it.

I have attached the error snapshot for the same i.e 1_err.png and 2_err.png

[image: 1_err.png]

[image: 2_err.png]

Comment: Please see [ask]: "Request you all to please help with this" is not a question, and software installation is not programming related ([help/on-topic]). Also, have you considered that your OS (a desktop OS) might not be supported by the Enterprise version of the software you're installing?

Comment: @OlafKock Noted. And regarding the enterprise edition, I have downloaded the software from https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/oracle19c-windows-downloads.html. Here, I could not see the standard edition so I can download it.

Comment: Can you check how long is your hostname? if longer than 15, try reducing it to 15 and check again

Comment: @gsalem Thanks for responding. I checked my hostname and it is of 11 char

Comment: Did you try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLGtKBwsK18

Comment: @Littlefoot Thanks for responding. Yes, I have done all the pre-requisite check but in this video he is not getting these kinds of error but for me it is popping up with warning window and then at later steps getting another error.

Comment: Can you also check if your %TEMP% disk has enough space?

Comment: @gsalem Thanks for responding. Yes, this folder also I had cleaned up. Still the same issue